# iOS swift - working with response from API

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I am very new to Swift and iOS development. And I am wondering how to do something relatively simple if I was using JavaScript.

I am making a call to an API that is returning the following. Excuse the formatting but it is directly copied from the Xcode console.

```
["type": success, "value": <__NSArrayI 0x600000030340>(
       {
          categories = ();
          id = 155;
          joke = "Chuck Norris does not &quot;style&quot; his hair. It lays perfectly in place out of sheer terror.";
       },
       {
            categories = (nerdy);
            id = 69;
            joke = "Scientists have estimated that the energy given off during the Big Bang is roughly equal to 1CNRhK (Chuck Norris Roundhouse Kick).";
       }
    )
]
```

I want to loop over the response and add to an array. In JavaScript it would look like the following:

```
let jokes = [];
response.value.forEach(item => {
   jokes.push(item.joke)
})
```

It doesn't have to be exactly like the above. I am confident using loops in swift and appending to an array. What I am struggling to do is access the jokes in the `value` array returned from the API.

My controller looks like the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/2")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                print(json["value"])
                // not sure how to access each joke in the array here
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason this is easy in JS and that there's additional work in in Swift is because you're on the border between typed and untyped behavior. JS & JSON - untyped. Swift would like to add some typing when reading the JSON; `Any` isn't all that useful without casting. There are several frameworks out there to help (e.g. SwiftyJSON) and Swift itself has added Codable/Decodable.

Comment: great, this is all brilliant to know @GrahamPerks. Just a question - lets say a production web React based app will be potentially making lots of API calls and storing this data in a redux store. Is there some similar approach with iOS development or is there something else I should be aware of?

Comment: That's a whole other question... I usually take one of 2 approaches. Parse & insert the downloaded data into SQLite, if I need it persistent. Or store it in RAM more like redux, e.g. with a singleton JokeManager class which can parse a JSON-derived dict `[String:Any]` into some useful Swift objects. Then the UI or whatever can pull jokes from `JokeManager.shared` as needed.

Comment: it sure is another question, but thanks for answering. Gives me something to research :-D -- but what you suggested is the method used for production apps?

Comment: SwiftyJSON looks great by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
if let va = json["value"] as? [[String:Any]] {
   va.forEach { print($0["joke"]) }
}
```

I would prefer to write a `Codable` structs for this

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let type: String
    let value: [Value]
}

struct Value: Codable {
    let categories: [Category]
    let id: Int
    let joke: String
}

struct Category: Codable {
}
```

---

```
let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from:data)
print(res.value)
```

Comment: That works thanks. Is this not a very common task in iOS/swift? as in web development it is. Is there a different approach to fetching data used in mobile applications that I am unaware of? Also, would you mind showing me how you would take the `struct` approach?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from logs the variable json["value"] is of type NSArray so you can do something like this to get your data (there are so many ways to do that).

First of all you can create the object Joke you wanna take like this

```
class Joke: NSObject {
     var categories = [String]()
     var id: Int?
     var joke: String?

     init(json: [String: Any]) {
         if let categories = json["categories"] as? String {
             for category in categories {
                 self.categories.append(category)
             }
         }
         if let id = json["id"] as? Int {
             self.id = id
         }
         if let joke = json[""] as? String {
             self.joke = joke
         }
     }
}
```

And then you do this in your ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var jokes = [Joke]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/2")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                print(json["value"])
                // not sure how to access each joke in the array here
                let arrayOfObject = json["value"] as! NSArray
                for object in arrayOfObject {
                    if let json = object as? [String: Any] {
                        let object = Joke(json: json)
                        // Now you have your object containing the data from the JSON and you can insert it in your array of Object
                        jokes.append(object)
                    }
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Remember, there are so many ways to do that, I showed you a simply way to do it, hope it will be helpful.